# Why "couldn't resolve host" error occur for avahi-daemon?

Tags: dns, avahi

I  couldn't connect Ubuntu with raspberrypi. I typed

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

but it shows “cannot resolve host.”

Answer (score 0):

For the ".local" domain to work you need a line in your /etc/nsswitch.conf file like:

## hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns

Comment: wow amazing .. thank you so much it works......